# Let's get critical: Jun 2013 Site Self-Evaluation

Tags: discussion, site-evaluation

We all love [Academia Stack Exchange](http://academia.stackexchange.com), but there is a whole world of people out there who need answers to their questions and don't even know that this site exists. When they arrive from Google, what will their first impression be? Let's try to look at this site through the eyes of someone who's never seen it before, and see how we stack up against the rest of the 'Net.

The [Site Self-Evaluation review queue](https://academia.stackexchange.com/review/site-eval) is open and populated with 10 questions that were asked and answered in the last quarter. Run a few Google searches to see how easy they are to find and compare the answers we have with the information available on other sites.

Rating the questions is only a part of the puzzle, though. Do you see a pattern of questions that should have been closed but are not? Questions or answers that could use an edit? Anything that's going really well? **Post an answer below to share your thoughts** and discuss these questions and the site's health with your fellow users!

Comment: Normally there are 10 questions but I only had 9, just curious how come?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

## Final Results

- [Very few research groups: continue doing PhD in this area?](https://academia.stackexchange.com/questions/9228/very-few-research-groups-continue-doing-phd-in-this-area)

  **Net Score: 5** (Excellent: 8, Satisfactory: 13, Needs Improvement: 3)
- [How do I make sure I get strong recommendation letters for faculty positions?](https://academia.stackexchange.com/questions/9341/how-do-i-make-sure-i-get-strong-recommendation-letters-for-faculty-positions)

  **Net Score: 18** (Excellent: 18, Satisfactory: 5, Needs Improvement: 0)
- [Scholarships in general and Ontario Trillium Scholarship in particular](https://academia.stackexchange.com/questions/9659/scholarships-in-general-and-ontario-trillium-scholarship-in-particular)

  **Net Score: 11** (Excellent: 11, Satisfactory: 11, Needs Improvement: 0)
- [Why do universities support faculty writing textbooks?](https://academia.stackexchange.com/questions/9372/why-do-universities-support-faculty-writing-textbooks)

  **Net Score: 16** (Excellent: 16, Satisfactory: 6, Needs Improvement: 0)
- [Do I have a MSc degree if I did the work but did not pay tuition?](https://academia.stackexchange.com/questions/9510/do-i-have-a-msc-degree-if-i-did-the-work-but-did-not-pay-tuition)

  **Net Score: 14** (Excellent: 14, Satisfactory: 7, Needs Improvement: 0)
- [How much effort does it take to record video courses?](https://academia.stackexchange.com/questions/9221/how-much-effort-it-takes-to-record-video-courses)

  **Net Score: 6** (Excellent: 9, Satisfactory: 8, Needs Improvement: 3)
- [Difficulty in admission to online software engineering graduate programs](https://academia.stackexchange.com/questions/9259/difficulty-in-admission-to-online-software-engineering-graduate-programs)

  **Net Score: 1** (Excellent: 5, Satisfactory: 10, Needs Improvement: 4)
- [What are the advantages of putting your dissertation on Facebook?](https://academia.stackexchange.com/questions/9314/putting-phd-dissertation-on-facebook)

  **Net Score: 11** (Excellent: 11, Satisfactory: 8, Needs Improvement: 0)
- [How to tell my advisor I don't want to stay in academia](https://academia.stackexchange.com/questions/9442/how-to-tell-my-advisor-i-dont-want-to-stay-in-academia)

  **Net Score: 17** (Excellent: 17, Satisfactory: 2, Needs Improvement: 0)
- [What should be included in a departmental email policy?](https://academia.stackexchange.com/questions/9557/what-should-be-included-in-a-departmental-email-policy)

  **Net Score: 8** (Excellent: 9, Satisfactory: 9, Needs Improvement: 1)

Answer (score 0):

I am a relative newcomer (and seemingly a chatty one at that), I have found that this site is very welcoming and willing to discuss all aspects of academic life - from undergraduate, through postgraduate to academic careers.  The answers are very thorough and well thought out.

Even though I am a newcomer, I thought I would give a perspective from this viewpoint.

Comment: As a newcomer, your perspective is especially useful. Thanks!